# facebook style navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, blueprint-css

Here is the navbar in my rails app. The problem is I am not sure if this wil work cross browser because I am adjusting the padding of the anchor tags to get the required height. THe other issue is the search form is inside this navbar and it's not vertically centered on inside it.

I basically want a facebook style navbar that has a few box like links(with hover) and a search form (a textbox and a search image both integrated/looking seamless). Right the search textbox and the buttom are not seamless they look separate.

Help appreciated.

```
<div class="span-24 last nav_container ui-state-default">
            <div class="main_links_div span-18">
              <ul><li id="home_nav"><a href="/">New</a></li><li id="post_nav"><a href="/post_topics">posts</a></li><li id="cat_nav"><a href="#">Categories</a></li><li id="city_nav"><a href="#">Cities</a></li></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="span-6 last div-search-form"><form method="get" id="search_form" class="right" action="/searches">
              <input type="text" value="City_Name" name="search_term" id="search_term" class="search-term">
                   <span class="small-button"><a id="search_button" href="#" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Search"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span></a></span>
                   </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

### THe css

```
main_links_div {
margin-bottom:0.4em;
vertical-align:baseline;
}

main_links_div ul {
display:inline;
margin-bottom:0 !important;
padding-left:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

main_links_div li {
display:inline;
}

main_links_div li a {
font-size:1em;
padding:0.7em 0.8em;
}

right {
float:right;
}
small-button {
font-size:0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using some sort of a grid framework that you did not specify, however, I am pretty sure this is what you are after:

```
#nav_container{
overflow:auto;
}

.main_links_div {
margin-bottom:0.4em;
}

.main_links_div ul {
margin-bottom:0 !important;
padding-left:0;
list-style:none;
}

.main_links_div li {
float:left;
}

.main_links_div li a {
font-size:1em;
height:1em;
padding:0.7em 0.8em;
}

#search_form {
float:left;
margin-left:5em;
}

.small-button {
font-size:0.8em;
}
```

Also remember to put the '.' before your class names!

Comment: Thanks. I do use blueprint. Sorry about the typo, the class names do indeed have a . before them. Let me give this a try!

Comment: Well that isn't exactly what I am looking for. It does align evverything vertically, but the search form and the links are of the same height. The links kinda look squished. I want the link to have more height than the search box..which basically increases the height of the overall nav bar and the link are of the same height and the search box is aligned vertically in the middle.

Comment: just use padding-top and padding-bottom to get whatever values you want.